# merge 2 xml file with xslt too slow

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a code to merge two xml file using xslt , the merge of the two files person1 and person2 work fine . I tried with an example with 10 000 records it s took 17 minutes but  when the number of record is 100 000 it take around 6 hours is that normal or I m missing something . thank you for any help.

first file persons1:

```
<personnes>
  <personne>
    <name>aaa</name>
    <age>10</age>
    <adress>aaaaaa</adress>
  </personne>

  <personne>
    <name>bbb</name>
    <age>10</age>
    <adress>aaaaaa</adress>
  </personne>

  <personne>
    <name>ccc</name>
    <age>20</age>
    <adress>cccccc</adress>
  </personne>

  <personne>
    <name>ddd</name>
    <age>10</age>
    <adress>cccccc</adress>
  </personne>


</personnes>
```

second file persons2:

```
<personnes>
  <personne>

    <id>1111</id>
    <quantity>1100</quantity>
  </personne>

  <personne>

     <id>2222</id>
     <quantity>2200</quantity>
  </personne>

  <personne>

    <id>3333</id>
    <quantity>3300</quantity>
  </personne>

  <personne>

    <id>4444</id>
    <quantity>4400</quantity>
  </personne>

  <personne>

    <id>5555</id>
    <quantity>5500</quantity>
  </personne>
</personnes>
```

and I want the result in a new xml file like bellow :

```
<personnes>
  <personne>
    <id>1111</id>
    <name>aaa</name>
    <quantity>1100</quantity>
    <age>10</age>
    <adress>aaaaaa</adress>
  </personne>

  <personne>
    <id>2222</id>
    <name>bbb</name>
    <quantity>2200</quantity>
    <age>10</age>
    <adress>aaaaaa</adress>
  </personne>

  <personne>
    <id>3333</id>
    <name>ccc</name>
    <quantity>3300</quantity>
    <age>20</age>
    <adress>cccccc</adress>
  </personne>

  <personne>
    <id>4444</id>
    <name>ddd</name>
    <quantity>4400</quantity>
    <age>10</age>
    <adress>cccccc</adress>
  </personne>


</personnes>
```

the xslt file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<!-- load the merge file -->
<xsl:variable name="personne2"
  select="document('file2.xml')"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

<personnes>
<xsl:for-each select="personnes/personne">


<xsl:variable name="elementposition" select="count(preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>

   <!-- copy the child nodes -->
   <personne>

   <xsl:copy-of select="$personne2/personnes/personne[position() = $elementposition]/id"/>
   <xsl:copy-of select="child::name"/>
   <xsl:copy-of select="$personne2/personnes/personne[position() = $elementposition]/quantity"/>
   <xsl:copy-of select="child::age"/>
   <xsl:copy-of select="child::address"/>

   </personne>
</xsl:for-each>
</personnes>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `<xsl:variable name="elementposition" select="count(preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>` it seems you can simply use `<xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>` and then directly use e.g. `$personne2/personnes/personne[$pos]/id`, that will probably be a performance boost as mantaining position for the `position()` function is done efficiently anyway while counting siblings again and again is costly.

With an XSLT 2 processor you could also consider to use a key together with `xsl:number` e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="2.0">


  <xsl:key name="pos" match="personne">
      <xsl:variable name="pos" as="xs:integer">
          <xsl:number/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:sequence select="$pos"/>
  </xsl:key>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- load the merge file 
    <xsl:variable name="personne2"
      select="document('file2.xml')"/>-->

    <!-- inlining here for the self-containedness of the example -->
    <xsl:variable name="personne2">
        <personnes>
          <personne>

            <id>1111</id>
            <quantity>1100</quantity>
          </personne>

          <personne>

             <id>2222</id>
             <quantity>2200</quantity>
          </personne>

          <personne>

            <id>3333</id>
            <quantity>3300</quantity>
          </personne>

          <personne>

            <id>4444</id>
            <quantity>4400</quantity>
          </personne>

          <personne>

            <id>5555</id>
            <quantity>5500</quantity>
          </personne>
        </personnes>        
    </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">

    <personnes>
      <xsl:for-each select="personnes/personne">



       <!-- copy the child nodes -->
       <personne>

           <xsl:copy-of select="key('pos', position(), $personne2)/id"/>
           <xsl:copy-of select="child::name"/>
           <xsl:copy-of select="key('pos', position(), $personne2)/quantity"/>
           <xsl:copy-of select="child::age"/>
           <xsl:copy-of select="child::address"/>

       </personne>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </personnes>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y8Q

XSLT 3 has more options with accumulators and `xsl:merge`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:accumulator name="pos" as="xs:integer" initial-value="0">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="personnes" select="0"/>
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="personnes/personne" select="$value + 1"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:mode use-accumulators="pos"/>    

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- load the merge file 
    <xsl:variable name="personne2"
      select="document('file2.xml')"/>-->

    <!-- inlining here for the self-containedness of the example -->
    <xsl:variable name="personne2">
        <personnes>
          <personne>

            <id>1111</id>
            <quantity>1100</quantity>
          </personne>

          <personne>

             <id>2222</id>
             <quantity>2200</quantity>
          </personne>

          <personne>

            <id>3333</id>
            <quantity>3300</quantity>
          </personne>

          <personne>

            <id>4444</id>
            <quantity>4400</quantity>
          </personne>

          <personne>

            <id>5555</id>
            <quantity>5500</quantity>
          </personne>
        </personnes>        
    </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:merge>
            <xsl:merge-source select="personne">
                <xsl:merge-key select="accumulator-before('pos')"/>
            </xsl:merge-source>
            <xsl:merge-source for-each-item="$personne2" select="personnes/personne">
                <xsl:merge-key select="accumulator-before('pos')"/>
            </xsl:merge-source>
            <xsl:merge-action>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of
                      select="current-merge-group()[2]/id, name, current-merge-group()[2]/quantity, age, adress"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:merge-action>
        </xsl:merge>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y8Q/2

Comment: thanks for the answer , I tried the first suggestion and didn t speed up , and I m trying the xslt 3.0 solution , I got an error : Parse Error in current-merge-group function. I don't have much experience with XSLT . can you please help on that ?

Comment: To be able to use XSLT 3.0, you of course need to use an XSLT 3.0 processor like a recent release of Saxon 9.8 or 9.9 or Altova 2017 or 2018 or 2019.

Comment: thanks, I got this error after I added the Saxon-HE 9.8 in POM.XML: SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser:
  file:.xsl<Line 1, Column 1>:
 XML-20180: (Error) User Supplied NodeFactory returned a Null Pointer.: Invalid URI for stylesheet: file:xsltFilePersonnes.xsl

Comment: If you are new to using Saxon 9 then I would suggest to first try using it from the command line as documented in http://saxonica.com/html/documentation9.8/using-xsl/commandline/. Once you have established that that works for you with your XSLT and a sample (perhaps for testing a small one) of your input documents try running it from code if that is what you want to do: how to do it is documented at http://saxonica.com/html/documentation9.8/using-xsl/embedding/. If any problems arise like that particular error, then please consider to raise that in a new question with the necessary details.

Comment: @OmarB., do you get a notable performance improvement now that you have moved to Saxon 9 and XSLT 3?

Comment: @ Marin Honnen, now is much better in few seconds with XSL3  instead of  hours using XSLT 1.0 .